# Brige Relays - help

Tags: configuration, relays, tails, bridge

This is impartant.

Do I need to configure Bridge relays to hide fact that surfing on deep
web .onion sites using USB Tails and Tor Browser?
Reading this
(https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en#AddTorWorks) my
understanding is - there is no bigger difference if I use Tor Browser
via tails or xp win if we are talking about the very fact of visibility
usage of Tor Browser - is just visible that someone, somewhere uses it -
correct me if wrong?

So in that case I wish to configure Brige Relays in my USB Tails Tor
Browser - following this path, it is necessary to hide the fact Tor
Browser - Yes or No?

Then adding bridges in Tor Browser when Tor does work in Tails is not
possible since there is no possible to open Tor Browser's Network
Settings - it shows only: New Identyty, Seciurity Settings, Check for
tor browser update.

This leads me to conclusion - Using Tails an Tor Browser there us no
need to set briges relays to hide fact of usage.

Please, give me a hint/shrt guide whether I need to set briges relays?

---

Can I use this to configure Tor Browser in Tails?
https://bridges.torproject.org/options

---

Thanks for help.
Regards,

Comment: If you want to hide fact that you are using Tor then bridge, specially with obfs4 transport can help.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what the config looks like:
- runing USB Tails
- no SSD/HHD drives in notebook (physically removed)
- tor browser configured via Briges - "Just give me bridges!"
(https://bridges.torproject.org/options)
- persistent storage is ON
- never open full-screen while web activity

1 Is this all what I need for good solution to anonymity in web
activity?
2 Should I focused on some additional settings? focus on some additional
aspects?
3 In this situation the VPN's config is makes no sense... no needed?
4 The biggest threat is a private WiFi network - better to use some
other?

I appreciate your support very much - Thank you.
Regards,

Comment: ..ok.. thanks for it. The is and web instruction how to configured well - bridge obfs4 in Tails?

Comment: Thats was helpful.
I manage to connect via brige with the simple one - "Just give me
bridges!"
However once I have taken a obfs4 one connection was for ever - like 30
min and no connection. Any idea? Thanks a lot for your time, I'm trying to support your org.
Regads